# How to estimate homography using RANSAC on SIFT mathing results

Tags: matlab, sift, homography, matlab-cvst

In image matching, with **Matlab**, I found a vector of correspondences of two images using Sift and now I have to estimate the homography matrix. Any simple way to do it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I found a very interesting paper: http://cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~cansin/projects/cs554-vision/image-stitching/image-stitching-paper.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book ["Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision"](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/) by Richard Hartley and Andrew Zisserman is an excellent resource for this sort of problem, and helpfully they also provide a set of Matlab functions to perform common tasks.  Look at [this page](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/code/) and download the file `vgg_H_from_x_lin.m`, which estimates the homography between two sets of points using a **linear** method.  Here's an example (with some completely made-up numbers):

```
x1 = [ 10 20; 13 23; 45 35 ].';
x2 = [ 103 301; 106 305; 80 229 ].';
H = vgg_H_from_x_lin(x1, x2);
```

Alternatively, download the file `ransacfithomography_vgg.m` to compute the homography using **RANSAC**.  This time you must give an inlier threshold for RANSAC.

```
x1 = [ 10 20; 13 23; 45 35 ].';
x2 = [ 103 301; 106 305; 80 229 ].';
H = ransacfithomography_vgg(x1, x2, 0.02);
```

Comment: thanks for these very usefull resources! I need another clarification: i have a vector of matching points, so what's the relation among these points and 'x1','x2'?

Comment: `x1` is a vector of points in image 1, `x2` is a vector of points in image 2.  They should be the same size, as each row in `x1` corresponds to matching points in the same row in `x2`.

Comment: ok, so, for each match, in x1 i've to put the (x,y,1) of image 1, and in x2 the corresponding point (x1,y1,1) of image 2. Right?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `estimateGeometricTransform` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.